# Making squares disappear - iOS

Tags: ios

I am planing to make an app for iPhone

I want to include some squares and assign a number to each square.

when a user taps on a square, it should disappear along with some other squares, for example:
If there are squares (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), the user selects 7 for example, so square number
7 should disappear along with all squares (square > 7) so the remaining squares must be
(1,2,3,4,5,6).

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Thank you very much guys for answering,, but sorry, I have just realised that it is impossible to present the squares as I thought before. As I was thinking to arrange the squares as a table, but I spent about 3 hours trying to assign the right numbers, I could not do it, and after searching, I found that no one ever got an answer to it :p .. I think I will try to find another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an NSArray of all the buttons and simply set the Alpha of the squares you wish to disappear.

Something like that:

```
-(void)removeSquersAfterSelection:(NSInteger)selectedSqure
{
  for(NSInteger i=0;i<squersArray;i++){
    if(i<=selectedSqure){
        [squersArray objectAtIndex:i].alpha = 0;
    }

  }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much guys for answering,, but sorry, I have just realised that it is impossible to present the squares as I thought before. As I was thinking to arrange the squares as a table, but I spent about 3 hours trying to assign the right numbers, I could not do it, and after searching, I found that no one ever got an answer to it :p .. I think I will try to find another method.

Comment: It is definitely  possible, can you explain what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have managed to do it using another method, what was impossible is the way of assigning the numbers to the squares using the method I thought of.

Answer (score 0):

```
[theSquare removeFromSuperview];
```

If you subclass a UIButton you can override this method and do some working out in it:

```
MyCustomButton *theSquare1 = [[MyCustomButton alloc] initWithSquareNumber:1];
[theSquare1 addTarget:self action:@selector(removeFromSuperview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in `MyCustomButton.m`:

```
- (void)removeFromSuperview {
    [super removeFromSuperview];
    // you can delete the button from the database or something here...
    // or keep score in the game or similar.
}
```

Then if you do what shani said and keep an array of these buttons you can iterate through them and find any higher than the one you've got.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for answering,, but sorry, I have just realised that it is impossible to present the squares as I thought before. As I was thinking to arrange the squares as a table, but I spent about 3 hours trying to assign the right numbers, I could not do it, and after searching, I found that no one ever got an answer to it :p .. I think I will try to find another method.